# Работа в Windows на C\C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Есть простая программа на С++ под Windows, которая открывает `файл` и которая лежит в `новая папка 1` на рабочем столе. Файл лежит в том же месте, где расположена и моя программа, то есть в `новая папка 1`. Так вот, если файл лежит в том же месте, где и моя программа, тогда он успешно открывается, но если я создаю `новая папка 2` в `новая папка 1` и туда помещаю свой файл, то он уже не открывается. Я понимаю, что мне нужно переместиться в `новая папка 2`, поэтому в код добавляю строку `system("cd новая папка 2");`. Но это не работает. Даже если я указываю весь путь `C:\Users\АНТОН\Desktop\новая папка 1\Новая папка 2`, то тоже не работает. Помогите, пожалуйста, что нужно прописать?

Comment: Надо открывать по абсолютному пути и использовать юникод. Ну или менять текущую папку у этого приложения а не у system.

Comment: Если имя файла, скажем, `filename`, то имя этого файла не в текущем каталоге, а в подкаталоге `новая папка 2` - `новая папка 2\filename`. Просто обращайтесь к нему по этому имени (не забывая в литералах в исходнике удваивать обратные косые). И - пока вы не разберетесь с юникодом и прочими вариантами работы с русским - используйте английские имена, типа, `new filder 2` :) - будет легче не решать одновременно две проблемы...

Answer (score 1):

> Так вот, если файл лежит в том же месте, где и моя программа, тогда он
>   успешно открывается

Это объясняется тем, что Windows ищет вначале файл в месте откуда исполняется программа...

> Даже если я указываю весь путь C:\Users\А...
>   Вероятно что указание пути не верно. Если оно указано в двойных кавычках, что наиболее вероятно, то перед каждым \ нужно писать такой же т.е. "C:\\Users\\А...".